# Dismiss UIActionSheet programatically in iOS 8 screws up UIApplication's windows/keyWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

**Story:**

I need to programatically dismiss a UIActionSheet when the app goes to background, and what I did in iOS 7, is to traversal `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows` and find a view which is of type `UIActionSheet`, then dismiss it. It does not work in iOS 8.

**Background:**

In iOS 8, `UIAlertController` should be used to present alert or action sheet, and a bit experiment shows that `UIActionSheet` is internally implemented using `UIAlertController`:

`po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] <_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow:`

`po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] <_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController: 0x7faa0cf049f0>`

`po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentedViewController] <UIAlertController: 0x7faa0c8cb9e0>`

Which has the correct title, message, etc.

**Confusion:**

I then added some code to dismiss the controller, and it does dismiss it. However, the app now does not respond to any user interaction, and I found that after dismissing, the `keyWindow` is still `_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow`, then I'm confused, shouldn't dismissing a presented controller clean up its window? Or, is it because it's dismissed just when the app goes to background so the window hierarchy is not in a normal state thus things are screwed up?

Can anyone provide some opinions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use dismissViewController on UIAlertController?

Comment: Thanks @sha I've tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Something else strange is going on if that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

At first I was stumped on this.  From the view controller I'm presenting from after dismissing the actionSheet I called this asssuming it would fix this issue:

```
[self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Totally didn't work.  The shimPresenterWindow is still the main window.

So I came up with a different idea.  As soon as you dismiss the alertController insert the following code:

```
NSString *windowDescription = NSStringFromClass([window class]);
        if ([windowDescription isEqualToString:@"_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow"]){
            window.hidden = YES;
        }
```

That combined with making the main window the visible one successfully gets the action sheet off the main view.  Please note that I'm not sure if this leads to memory leaks of any kind.